# jQuery event bind works with plain link but now with link with image

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('a.connect').bind("click", function(event)
            {
                    var str = event.target.id;
                    alert (str);
                    var uid = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1);
                    //connect (uid);
            });
    });
</script>
```

When I use the following HTML

```
<a class="connect button-small-blue" id="connect_{$uid}" href="#">Connect</a>
```

everything works great. However, when I use

```
<a class="connect" id="connect_{$uid}" href="#"><img src="{$imgSocialConnect}" alt="{$lblSocialConnect}" title="{$lblSocialConnect}" /></a>
```

The alert(str) call comes up empty.

I just figured out that when I replace the alert call with

```
alert (jQuery(this).attr('id') );
```

the ID is retrieved correctly.

Can anybody shine some light on this and tell me what's going on why the 2nd HTML variant is not working with the jQuery function as it is now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when you click in the second variant case, you are really clicking **in the image**, the click event then propagates to the enclosing `a` element, so when you print the `event.target.id` you are trying to access the `id` of the image, which does not exist, and so you get an empty string.

You can test by doing this in your second variant case:

```
alert(event.target.tagName);
```

that should give you **IMG** .

To access the `id` of the `a` element in the second variant case, just do `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Your alert statement returns "IMG". Now, what do I have to in order to get the ID of the link tag which surrounds the image?

Comment: Just do $(this).attr('id')  inside your click handler. Updated answer with that.